# Call Get & Set methods outside class

Tags: c#

How am I able to call the crypt method from another class and insert setmethod or getmethod? The password is loading from textbox.

```
public partial class LogUser : Form
{

   private string userPassword;
   // textbox where user insert password 
   public string GetUserPassword()
   {
      return userPassword;
   }

   public void SetUserPassword(string userPassword)
   {
      this.userPassword = userPassword;
   }

   private void loginUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
          MyFunctions.Crypt(GetUserPassword());
          // compilator error.
   }      // can't convert from 'string' to 'Project.LogUser'
}

class MyFunctions
{



   public static string Crypt(string cryptPassword)
   {
      Random ra = new Random();
      int key = Rando.Rand(ra, 22, 4);
      LogUser cryptingPw = new LogUser();
      string crypt = Encrypting(cryptPassword, key);
      return crypt;
   }
}
```

I have updated my question. So the Encrypting method is excepting an object...

Comment: You can call it with `MyFunctions.Crypt` if your scope allows it.

Comment: Look at the types of your arguments. That is your problem. `GetUserPassword` gives a string, but your `Crypt` function is expecting a `LogUser`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are passing the return value of your method GetUserPassword() to the Crypt method.
That method is expecting a LogUser as Input. Which is not a string.

I think you want to modify the signature of your Crypt method to accept a string as input, to get rid of the compile error.

Answer (score 0):

In place of this code:

```
MyFunctions.Crypt(GetUserPassword());
```

Write this code:

```
LogUser objLogUser = new LogUser();
MyFunctions.Crypt(objLogUser);
```

Comment: That gets rid of the compile error, but will not give the desired result, because the newly created `LogUser` object does not contain the password that the user entered. The OP could simply pass `this` as argument, or better, refactor the `Crypt` method to take a string as argument.